# How to enable @ConditionalOnProperty in spring-boot on runtime changeable property

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two class which depends on config variable:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("config.db")
public class DatabaseTokenStore implements TokenStore {
}

@Component
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(DatabaseTokenStore.class)
public class SimpleTokenStore implements TokenStore {
}
```

so when db is true then `DatabaseTokenStore` class is autowired when false then `SimpleTokenStore` is autowired. Problem is that I can change this property in runtime with `CRaSH`. Then this mechanic will not work. Is there some way how to change implement of interface in runtime ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make sense? You're creating singleton (the default scope) objects. So your beans are created once when the application starts. You will only have one TokenStore.

Comment: I am confused of what you want to achieve. You could simply initialize both beans as singletons, make a custom class with a `getTokenStore()` method, that checks your propery value at runtime. And then inject this "resolver-type" class where you want to use the `TokenStore`s. I am not aware of spring-boot being able to determine runtime conditional injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize both `TokenStore`s on startup. And create a resolver to inject into classes where you need to work with them. Like so:

```
@Component
public class HelloStoreResolver {

    @Autowired
    private HelloStore oneHelloStore;

    @Autowired
    private HelloStore twoHelloStore;

    public HelloStore get() {
        if (condition) {
            return oneHelloStore;
        } else {
            return twoHelloStore;
        }
    }

}


@Component
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloStoreResolver helloResolver;

    //annotations omitted
    public String sayHello() {
        return helloResolver.get().hello();
    }

}
```